# What kind of process is a locally bounded process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

A definition of locally bounded process is on [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/localpropertiesofprocesses).

On that website, it says any discrete-time predictable process is locally bounded. How can I prove this?  Why this is not true for continuous-time predictable process?  How about if I add in "Usual condition" (i.e. complete, right continuous filtration.)

Can I say any Cadlag process is locally bounded?